# Does doctrine support composite keys in many-to-many join tables?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, composite-primary-key

I have entities `Channel` and `Post`. `Channel` has simple integer `id`. `Post` has composite key made of its own `id` and `channel_id`.

I would like to have many-to-many relationship between those entities(mention), so that one `Post` might have many mentioned `Channel`s and `Channel` might be mentioned by many `Posts`.

The question is - if it is supported by Doctrine, how do I implement such relationship?

```
Domain\Telegram\Models\Channel:
  type: entity
  id:
    id:
      type: integer

  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      nullable: true

  oneToMany:
    posts:
      targetEntity: Domain\Telegram\Models\Post
      mappedBy: channel


Domain\Telegram\Models\Post:
  type: entity
  id:
    channel:
      associationKey: true
    id:
      type: integer

  manyToOne:
    channel:
      targetEntity: Domain\Telegram\Models\Channel
      inversedBy: posts
```

**Update and solution**

Solution by @WilliamPerron almost worked. If used in its current state, `doctrine:schema:validate` returns an error :

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Domain\Telegram\Models\Channel' mapping is invalid:
>
> The inverse join columns of the many-to-many table 'mentions' have to contain to ALL identifier columns of the target entity
>   'Domain\Telegram\Models\Post', however 'channel_id' are missing.

inverseJoinColumns section should look like this:

```
    inverseJoinColumns:
      post_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
      post_channel_id:
        referencedColumnName: channel_id
```

So this kind of relationship is practically same as simple many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, this is possible

You simply need to specifify which table it joins to with the `groups` element, and then the entity it maps to. For a uniderectional relationship, the schema would look like this:

```
Channel:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    posts:
      targetEntity: Post
      joinTable:
        name: posts_channels
        joinColumns:
          channel_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          post:
            referencedColumnName: id
```

and for a bidirectional relationship, you would need to add the `inversedBy` element:

```
Channel:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    posts:
      targetEntity: Post
      inversedBy: channels
      joinTable:
        name: posts_channels
        joinColumns:
          channel_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          post_id:
            referencedColumnName: id

Post:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    channels:
      targetEntity: Channel
      mappedBy: posts
```

The official documentation for this can be found [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).

Comment: Are you sure that your answer applies to the situation with composite keys?  AFAIK your code does not show any awareness of it.

Comment: @svgrafov the grat thing about Doctrine's Many-to-Many relationship is that it will take care of mapping the IDs correctly, and return all associated records in an `ArrayCollection`, so there is no need to use a composite key at all

Comment: Can you update your code (particularly, `joinColumns` part) to be closer to my situation?